# Serializing GradientBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, brush

I'm trying to save a Brush object using serializing but I get error below:

> Type 'System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush' in Assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable

How can I save a Brush object into a file?

Comment: What do you mean by "save a Brush object to an object"?  Please explain what you're trying to accomplish, not what you're trying to do .

Comment: Rather than saving a brush object to a file, why not just save its values?

Comment: I want to save skin settings for my app.

Comment: I can't save values because there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new GradientStopCollection(
    new GradientStop[] { new GradientStop(Colors.Blue, 2.0), new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 3.0) }));

using (var outfile = File.CreateText("Brush.xaml"))
{
    XamlWriter.Save(brush, outfile);
}
```

Which produces the following:

```
<LinearGradientBrush xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF0000FF" Offset="2" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0000" Offset="3" />
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```